# MySQL ORDER BY not sorting alphabetically

Tags: mysql

I am in the process of learning MySQL and have a database full of books. For whatever reason ORDER BY has stopped sorting alphabetically and I can't seem to figure out why. The code itself is pretty simple

```
SELECT author_fname, author_lname, Min(released_year) FROM books GROUP BY 2, 1;
```

I get output table that is grouped(I know this because of the duplicates that I have in the DB) but it is not sorted alphabetically. Strangely enough yesterday all of my ORDER BY queries worked perfectly.

Does anyone have any idea of why this might be? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You have no `ORDER BY` in your query

Comment: Ahh I assumed GROUP BY also sorted alphabetically for me! Dumb mistake haha, thank you

Comment: *I assumed GROUP BY also sorted alphabetically for me!* This was true in ancient versions. Now you need in explicit ORDER BY.